# How to correctly rethrow an exception of task already in faulted state?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a synchronous method which, amongst other things, checks the status of a pending task and rethrows its exception, if any:

```
void Test(Task task)
{
    // ...
    if (task.IsFaulted)
        throw task.Exception;
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't propagate the exception stack trace information and is debugger-unfriendly.

Now, if the `Test` was `async`, it would not be as simple and natural as this:

```
async Task Test(Task task)
{
    // ...
    if (task.IsFaulted)
        await task; // rethrow immediately and correctly
    // ...
}
```

**Question: how to do it right for a synchronous method?** I have come up with this but I do not like it:

```
void Test(Task task)
{
    // ...
    if (task.IsFaulted)
        new Action(async () => await task)();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe try accessing task.Result?

Comment: @Strilanc, this is a non-generic `Task` task, so it doesn't have `Result`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To properly re-throw an exception, you should use `ExceptionDispatchInfo`:

```
ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(task.Exception.InnerException).Throw();
```

You *can* also do:

```
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

P.S. Your `Action` approach will not work correctly, since you're creating an `async void` method, and you cannot catch exceptions propagated from that method.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary for the comprehensive answer, I have learnt a new thing about `async void`. I thought, because `task` is already in completed state, the `new Action(async () => await task)()` lambda will be executed synchronously and hence throw on the calling thread's synchronization context. Indeed, it executes synchronously, but the exception doesn't get propagated to the calling context.

Comment: I just realized I can also use `task.Wait()` to rethrow inside a non-async method, i.e. `if (task.IsFaulted) task.Wait();`. I do get `AggregatedException` though. Does it make sense?

Comment: @avo: Yes, that makes sense. `Wait` is a holdover in the `Task` type from its original design, which was as part of the Parallel Task Library. So `Wait` (and `Result`) will 1) block the thread if necessary, and 2) wrap any errors in `AggregateException`. This is expected, and it's why my sample code actually throws the `InnerException`.

Comment: @StephenCleary has more on this topic at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html